# What is the complexity to compute the sample entropy of a time series of length N?

Tags: time-series, entropy, time-complexity

**background**
Some algorithms are linear in operations, so the number of operations to complete is $O \left(N\right)$, while others are quadratic $O\left(N^2\right)$, cubic $O \left(N^3\right)$, or non-integer $O \left(N\cdot log N \right)$.

[Sample entropy](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/pracma/html/entropy.html) has been around for a while ([link](https://www.pnas.org/doi/10.1073/pnas.88.6.2297)) but I can't seem to find a clear statement showing the relationship between time-series length and number of operations to estimate the number of operations given the number of elements in the series.

For example, Matrix inversion can have complexity of $O \left(N^{2.778} \right)$ ([link](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-022-05172-4)).

**question**
What is the expected relationship between number of operations and time-series length?  If you need to include a term for complexity, feel free, but I was hoping for a mostly average answer.  Derivation would be nice but references are required.

**(*Updated 2-Aug-2023*)**
question (from comments) - which algorithm?

- First version: R::pracma::sample_entropy ([link](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/pracma/html/entropy.html))
  (I think its from Pincus 1991, [link](https://www.pnas.org/doi/10.1073/pnas.88.6.2297) )
- Alternate version: Python::entropy.sample_entropy ([link](https://raphaelvallat.com/entropy/build/html/generated/entropy.sample_entropy.html))
  (I think its from ([here](https://journals.physiology.org/doi/pdf/10.1152/ajpheart.2000.278.6.H2039)), but seems to split at N = 5000 into numba vs. mne speedups)

Comment: It looks like sample entropy for subsequences of length $m$ could be computed in $O(mN\log(N))$ time asymptotically in the time series length $N$ by using a suitable spatial index--but implementing it would be more effort than it's worth.  Since this is an implementation-dependent question, why not just run a standard benchmark test to *observe* what the asymptotic performance is?

Comment: @EngrStudent You'd need to specify an algorithm. More than once I've taken code that implemented say a naive $O(n^4)$ algorithm (or worse) for something and refined it several times, until it was $O(n^2)$, for example. That sort of thing can make the difference between "start it running and go have a long lunch" or even sometimes "start it running on a supercomputer and wait five weeks" and the much more practical *<press Enter> ... "Oh, it's done"*. ... Even algorithms with the same $O$ can differ dramatically in run time, and sometimes it's the difference between "can't afford it" and "free"

Comment: @whuber - I like empirical, but languages can have both speedups and bottlenecks that are non-obvious.  For simple tests they are less likely to show up but for complex ones it is more likely they can hit.  I also wanted to be able to point to an authoritative reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on the implementation. [pracma::sample_entropy](https://github.com/cran/pracma/blob/master/R/entropy.R#L31) suggests the time complexity is $O(N^3)$ with a for loop + vector-matrix Kronecker product. [This code for sample entropy](https://gist.github.com/schochastics/e3684645763e93cbc2ed7d1b70ee5fe6) shows the time complexity is $O(N^2)$. When you look at [this paper](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/23064819/), the authors briefly talk about how to implement sample entropy. In particular, they mention:

> Comparisons were then
> made against each m-length vector within the time
> series.

This part requires $O(N^2)$ to compute.